# How to Read the Result of Query into a Dask Dataframe in a Distributed Client?

Tags: python, sql, dask, dask-distributed

Trying to read the results of a query (from an AWS athena database) to a dask dataframe. Following the [`read_sql_query`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.read_sql_query.html#dask.dataframe.read_sql_query) method of the official documentation.

Here is how I am calling it.

```py
from dask import dataframe
query:sqlalchemy.Query
engine:sqlalchemy.Engine

dataframe.read_sql_query(sql=query.statement, con=str(engine.url), index_col='date') # AttributeError: 'OptionEngine' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

So, why this `AttributeError` when the documentation says I have to pass a string for the `con` argument? Should it be some other string?
Note that the query is working fine without dask, so the database configuration parameters are alright.

Also, I am looking for a read method that can scale to a multinode dask cluster without having to collect all the results at the driver node.

Comment: Hi, could you post the complete stack trace of the exception?